# Cordova Android status Bar set to transparent

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use this plugin below to set the statusbar to transparent. But i can not achieve it, i can change it to different colours, but not transparent. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Also it works on my Android 5.0.2, but not 5.0.

I tried just leaving out the hexcode value like they suggested but doesnt work, i tried all those below, none of those set my statusbar to transparent.

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor"/>

    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />



if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I have the same issue

Comment: Not on Android 5.0....only on the versions after that

Answer (score 8):

I tried so long to fix this issue. There is no documentation how to make status bar transparent for Android included paddings for the `<ion-header>`

So here is how i fixed it. After platform ready in *app.component.ts*:

```
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
   Plugins.StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({overlay: true});
   Plugins.StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({color: '#33000000'});
}
```

Don't set background color if you want your status bar transparent. In my case it will be a black status bar with 20% opacity.

[image: black status bar with 20% opacity]

And **DONT'T FORGET** to force Ionic for the statusbar padding when you import its modules in *app.module.ts*. Otherways your header will be sticky to the status bar:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({_forceStatusbarPadding: true})
```

Versions:

- ionic-native/status-bar: ^5.0.0
- capacitor/android: ^2.1.0

Comment: Is there any reason that "_forceStatusbarPadding" is still not documented in Ionic docs? ^^

Comment: _forceStatusbarPadding is an internal parameter, they dont recommend to use it, but i couldnt find another way to get the status bar padding

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15624#issuecomment-447091433

Answer (score 3):

Using
[IONIC Native Status Bar Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar)

app.component.ts:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
...
...
constructor(private platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar){
  this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#33000000');
  });
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({_forceStatusbarPadding: true})
```

Answer (score -5):

I just found it, its not mention in their documentation, but its simple as that:

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="transparent" />
```

And voilà, Its working :)

Comment: @Eusthace You need to install the plugin StatusBarBackgroundColor first
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`
See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#statusbarstyleblacktranslucent

Comment: Adding the above line to config.xml does not make status bar transparent at all.

Comment: This is an old comment, I guess they removed it since then.